same exact samba code on two different pcs not working
First time using samba, i tried to set it up on a vm where i crated a super simple config but it wont run, unix user has permissions.
I tried that same config on 3 different virtual machines, 2 out of 3 do not work.
In those that do not work i can see the "test" shared folder but after clicking on it, and after putting username and password of "prova" user, a pop up comes out saying that i should conctact adming and that i do not have permissions (on windows 11, i've even tried on linux same error kinda).
Please save me :(
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = never
   usershare allow guests = no

[test]
    path = /home/ubuntuserver/test/
    read only = no
    browsable = yes
    valid users = prova

